# db2 for zos - prohibit changes in columns

Tags: db2, zos, db2-zos

I would like to ask if there is a way to prohibit programs to change data in certain columns, at db2 level.

The problem is that I have some programs that change data in a group of tables but now I must not change data in some columns and I would like to know if there is a way that db2 can make that restriction.

I could change all the programs but would like to know if there is an easier way to block changes in a column.

Comment: Those existing programs that modify data in specific column(s), are they to be modified?  What do you expect those programs to do , if they try to modify data in specific column and Db2 prevents it and throws an error?

Comment: yes, I was expecting an error changing data in that columns

Answer (score 1):

You may create, let's say, `BEFORE UPDATE OF COL1, ..., COLx` [trigger](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_12.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_createtrigger.html) on this table with a [SIGNAL statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_12.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_signalstatement4nativesqlpl.html) inside.
Alternatively you may revoke the `update` privilege on this table from everyone and grant `update` on a subset of columns needed only.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create a view with a subset of the columns you need to update. It may be a little more complex in case you need to rebind your program(s)